# Mobile view width of column not expanding to 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have a row of "boxes" with a line between each as a border, and am having difficulty getting them to expand to 100% of the width when the browser width changes.

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="vlr">
   <div class="col-1">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="border-left:1px solid #909090;height:250px" class="border"></div> <!--this is just a border-->
   <div class="col-25" id="txtbox1">
      <div>Some text</div>
   </div>
   <div style="border-left:1px solid #909090;height:250px" class="border"></div>
   <div class="col-25" id="txtbox2">
      <div>Some text</div>
   </div>
   <div style="border-left:1px solid #909090;height:250px"></div>
   <div class="col-5" id="txtbox3">
      <div class="content">Some text</div>
   </div>
   <div style="border-left:1px solid #909090;height:250px" class="border"></div>
   <div class="col-1">&nbsp;</div>
```

I have 12 columns. I've defined col-25 as having a width of 20.83%.
CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

#txtbox1{
    display:block;
}

#txtbox2{
    display:block;
}

#txtbox3{
    display:block;
}

.border {
    display:none;
}

}
```

I've tried the CSS both with and without the display:block; neither work. However, the display:none for the borders /does work when I shrink the browser size.

Comment: Have you tried adding `{margin:none;}` to your class CSS?

Comment: Just tried; the boxes still remain on one row.